# PHP: on 32 bit system INT_MAX displays wrong?

Tags: php, overflow, compatibility, hex

I was simply wishing to test for overflow on an integer, such as in C (well, if it were just over integer max anyway). When I looked to see if PHP was actually doing what I told it to, it seems it fails for some reason. Here are my tests of the problem:

```
define('INT_MAX', 0x7FFFFFFF);
print "In decimal: " . hexdec(INT_MAX) . "<br/>";
print "In decimal: " . hexdec(0x7FFFFFFE) . "<br/>"; //Under int_max
print "In hex: " . dechex(hexdec(INT_MAX)) . "<br/>";
print "Float: " . ((bool)is_float(INT_MAX)?'true':'false') . "<br/>";
```

Results being:

> In decimal: 142929835591
>   In decimal: 142929835590
>   In hex: 47483647
>   Float: false

As I saw on the manual, it will cast to float if overthrown, but it seems to not and is clearly way higher. Am I being insane and missing something here, or is there some odd problem I should really need to know about when working with hexidecimal in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define('INT_MAX', 0x7FFFFFFF);
```

This defines `INT_MAX` to be integer `2147483647`. It is unnecessary to interpret it as a hexadecimal number. If you really want to use `INT_MAX` as a literal hexadecimal value, then you need to declare it as `'7FFFFFFF'` (inside a string); then the `hexdec` function will interpret the hexadecimal notation and convert it to a decimal value.

```
print(dechex(INT_MAX) . "\n");
```

This prints "`7fffffff`".

Comment: I wasn't aware that the hexadecimal notation only stored it in decimal in the end. I was just reconverting it from hex incorrectly, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your program makes no sense, because you are taking `0x7FFFFFFF` which is `2147483647`, and then treating it like `0x2147483647`, which is `142929835591` in decimal.

Anyway, PHP already has a constant that you can use:

```
var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX + 1); // converted to float
```